# Attempt to connect to SSH leads to inability to use VScode via attempting to set up SSH host indefinitely

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, ssh

[This is what I see after I try to set up my SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e8Ze.png)
So, I was trying to connect my VSCode to the AWS EC2 Instance. After I installed the SSH Host extension, I set up a new SSH target by clicking on the SSH - Host tab. I then typed in what amazon web services told me to in order to connect(ex: ssh -i "notTheRealKey.pem@ec2..."). Note, that is just an example link, not the one I actually used. However, I seem to be indefinitely setting up the SSH host and now I can't do anything with my VScode software. I can't even open a file! It doesn't work by reinstalling the software, either. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is stored in the ssh config file on  your system. You can remove it by editing `~/.ssh/config` and removing the bad entry.

Comment: How do I edit "~/.ssh/config"  ?

Comment: Use another text editor besides vs code in this case.

Comment: I can do that but I need hyper-specificity. I wouldn't even know how to begin to edit this.

Comment: It's safe to delete the file as well, it will be regenerated.

Comment: This does not help me. If I don't know how to edit it then I don't know how to delete it as well.